# Unexpected token < in JSON at position at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)

Tags: php, javascript, angularjs, ajax, ionic

```js
angular.module('app.controllers', [])


.controller('AuthLoginCtrl', ['$scope', 'restApi', '$state', 'auth',
     function ($scope, restApi, $state, auth) {
        $scope.ingresar = function () {
            restApi.call({
                method: 'post',
                url: 'auth/autenticar',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: {
                    Correo: $scope.Correo,
                    Password: $scope.Password
                },
                response: function (r) {
                    if (r.response) {
                        auth.setToken(r.result);
                        $state.go('pedidos');
                    } else {
                        alert(r.message);
                    }
                },
                error: function (r) {

                },
                validationError: function (r) {

                }
            });
        }
  }])
```

```html
<?php
use App\Lib\Auth,
    App\Lib\Response,
    App\Validation\EmpleadoValidation,
    App\Middleware\AuthMiddleware;

$app->group('/auth/', function () {
    $this->post('autenticar', function ($req, $res, $args) {
        $parametros = $req->getParsedBody();        
        
        return $res->withHeader('Content-type', 'application/json')
                   ->write(
                     json_encode($this->model->auth->autenticar($parametros['Correo'], $parametros['Password']))
                   );
    });
});
```

El error es causado aparentemente por la etiqueta `ion-content` de `ionic`, cuando quito la etiqueta se soluciona pero tengo que usarla de todas formas.

```
angular.module('your_app_name.services', [])

.factory('auth', ['$state', function ($state) {
    var auth = {
        setToken: function (token) {
            localStorage[API.token_name] = token;
        },
        getToken: function () {
            return localStorage[API.token_name];
        },
        getUserData: function () {
            try{
                var token = localStorage[API.token_name];
                if (token === '') return;

                var base64Url = token.split('.')[1];
                var base64 = base64Url.replace('-', '+').replace('_', '/');

                return window.atob(base64).data;                
            } catch(err) {
                $state.go('auth.login');
            }
        },
        logout: function () {
            localStorage[API.token_name] = '';
            $state.go('auth.login');
        },
        hasToken: function () {
            return (localStorage[API.token_name] !== '');
        },
        redirectIfNotExists: function () {
            if (!auth.hasToken()) {
                $state.go('auth.login');
            }
        }
    };

    return auth;
}])

.service('loader', function () {
    this.show = function (show) {
        document.querySelector("#loader").style.display = show ? 'block' : 'none';
    };
})

.service('restApi', ['$http', 'loader', 'auth', function ($http, loader, auth) {
    this.call = function (config) {
        var headers = {};
        headers[API.token_name] = auth.getToken();

        //loader.show(true);

        var http_config = {
            method: config.method,
            url: API.base_url + config.url,
            data: typeof (config.data) === 'undefined' ? null : config.data,
            headers: headers
        };

        $http(http_config).then(function successCallback(response) {
            //loader.show(false);
            config.response(response.data);
        }, function errorCallback(response) {
            //loader.show(false);

            switch (response.status) {
                case 401: // No autorizado
                    auth.logout();
                    break;
                case 422: // Validación
                    config.validationError(response.data);
                    break;
                default:
                    config.error(response);
                    console.log(response.statusText);
                    break;
            }
        });
    };
}])
```

Comment: ¿Puedes compartir el JSON que falla?

Comment: <?php
use App\Lib\Auth,
    App\Lib\Response,
    App\Validation\EmpleadoValidation,
    App\Middleware\AuthMiddleware;

$app->group('/auth/', function () {
    $this->post('autenticar', function ($req, $res, $args) {
        $parametros = $req->getParsedBody();        
        
        return $res->withHeader('Content-type', 'application/json')
                   ->write(
                     json_encode($this->model->auth->autenticar($parametros['Correo'], $parametros['Password']))
                   );
    });
});

Comment: Eso no es JSON (aunque parece que debiera generar JSON) y comienza por `<` lo que explicaría el mensaje de error. ¿Seguro que ese PHP se está procesando y no devolviendo sin más?

Comment: pero solo pasa cuando quiero usar el codigo en ionic sale el error causado por la etiqueta ion-content

Comment: @FmcvMcv el error te está saliendo muy probablemente porque el servidor no te está devolviendo nada, por lo tanto el JSON no puede parsear nada y da error, fíjate bien en si el servidor te está devolviendo datos haciendo un console.log() antes del parseo.

Comment: no recibo datos pero al quitar la etiqueta <ion-content> recibo datos y ya no da error estoy usando jwt en mi api.Gracias Javi